# How to create singleton DB instance

Tags: go, singleton, go-gorm

I referred a few code samples of how to create go singleton but I wish to have methods in those and call them on their singleton reference. My Code is as follows

```
package dbprovider

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _"github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
    "rest/article"
    "log"
)

type DBOperations interface {
    AddArticle(article *article.Article)
}

type DBManager struct {
    db            *gorm.DB
    isInitialized bool
}

var dbManagerInstance = new()

func GetDBManager() DBManager {
    return dbManagerInstance
}

func new() DBManager {
    localDbRef, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "../articles.db")
    if (err != nil) {
        panic("Error initializing db")
    } else {
        log.Print("DB Initialized successfully")
    }
    return DBManager{db:localDbRef, isInitialized:true}
}

func (dbManager DBManager)  AddArticle(article article.Article) (err error) {
    if (dbManager.isInitialized) {
        tx := dbManager.db.Begin()
        //dbManager.db.NewRecord(article)
        //dbManager.db.Commit()
        tx.NewRecord(article)
        tx.Commit()
        errs := dbManager.db.GetErrors()
        if (len(errs) > 0) {
            err = errs[0]
        } else {
            log.Print("No error in this transactions")
        }

    }
    return
}
```

**With a new answer I have updated this question including answer. But I have a few queries. How to cathc and return exception from gorm.Create(..)**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way is to create an exported interface with the methods, and make the implementing type unexported. Create a global variable of the interface type, and initialize it with a package `init()` function. You don't need any synchronization as the package `init()` function will run only once, safely.

Package `init()` functions are executed once, automatically, by the runtime, before you could refer to anything from the package. For details, see [Spec: Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization).

For example:

```
package dbprovider

type Manager interface {
    AddArticle(article *article.Article) error
    // Add other methods
}

type manager struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

var Mgr Manager

func init() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "../articles.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to init db:", err)
    }
    Mgr = &manager{db: db}
}

func (mgr *manager) AddArticle(article *article.Article) (err error) {
    mgr.db.Create(article)
    if errs := mgr.db.GetErrors(); len(errs) > 0 {
        err = errs[0]
    }
    return
}
```

Using it:

```
import "dbprovider"

if err := dbprovider.Mgr.AddArticle(someArticle); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

You could also do it without an `init()` function, e.g.:

```
var Mgr = newManager()

func newManager() Manager {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "../articles.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to init db:", err)
    }
    return &manager{db: db}
}
```

With this you may decide to make `newManager()` exported and users of your package could decide to use the shared `Mgr` instance, or they could create another `Manager`, e.g. for testing purposes.

**Notes:** `Mgr` is an exported global variable, and it is possible to assign a new value to it by other packages (e.g. `dbprovider.Mgr = nil`). If you want to avoid this, you have to make it unexported, and provide a "getter" function for it, e.g.:

```
var mgr = newManager()

func Mgr() Manager { return mgr }
```

And using it:

```
err := dbprovider.Mgr().AddArticle(someArticle)
```

Comment: from where this init method is getting called?

Comment: @sector11 Package `init()` functions are executed once automatically, by the runtime, before you could refer to anything from the package. See edited answer.

Comment: Getting cannot use localDbRef (type *gorm.DB) as type gorm.DB in field value

Comment: @sector11 Edited code a couple of times, make sure you use the current version. If still doesn't work, please post your version.

Comment: have updated  my question with you answer ontl thing i wish to know now is how to get error from Create function if it fails.

Comment: @sector11 My answer already contains error handling. After calling `DB.Create()`, the `DB.GetErrors()` is called to check for errors, and if there were any, the first is returned, which must be checked at the caller (where `Manager.AddArticle()` is called).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131130/discussion-between-sector11-and-icza).

Comment: What's difference between this way and this: http://marcio.io/2015/07/singleton-pattern-in-go/ ?

Comment: @TomSawyer The difference is that in the example you liked, the library only creates the singleton when first needed. In my example I create it during package init which is only run once, so the initialization and access to this variable later on does not introduce data race.

Comment: @icza i see he said: `The reason this is bad is that if references to the singleton instance are being held around through the code, there could be potentially multiple instances of the type with different states, generating potential different code behaviours` I'm not sure about thread-safe with Go with it seems the way you're doing here make no difference?

Comment: @TomSawyer My singleton instance has no mutable state, so what you quoted does not apply here ("with different states").

Comment: @icza Is there a way to not have `func (mgr *manager) AddArticle(...` in the dbprovider package but instead import the dbprovider package in a models package and add that function and others there?

Comment: @drack Yes, you could embed the `Manager` type in your model types, that way your model types would have all the methods as well. You could also embed an interface type having only the relevant subset of the `Manager` type, relevant to the embedder model type.

Comment: @icza thanks, the latter is what I think I'm trying to do. I just asked a new question more specific to what I'm trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438104/using-a-singleton-database-class-with-separate-models-and-services-packages

Comment: This solution could bring troubles with go routines trying to use the same singleton at the same moment?

Comment: @YagoAzedias Accessing the singleton is safe because package init runs in a single goroutine. And if `gorm.DB` is safe for concurrent access (to my knowledge it is), so will the singleton manager.