# Using a singleton database class with separate models and services packages

Tags: go

My question is similar to [How to create singleton DB class in GoLang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257847/how-to-create-singleton-db-class-in-golang/41258099) but I'm having trouble getting it to work with separate models and services packages.

project/lib/database/mysql.go:

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

type Manager struct {
    *gorm.DB
}

var Mgr *Manager

func init() {
    dsn := MysqlConnectionString("parseTime=true")
    tablePrefix := "demo"
    var err error

    gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, defaultTableName string) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v_%v", tablePrefix, defaultTableName)
    }

    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    Mgr = &Manager{db}
}
```

project/lib/models/retailer_keys.go

```
package models

import (
    "fmt"
    "project/lib/database"
    "time"
)

type RetailerKeysInterface interface {
    RetailerKeys() ([]*RetailerKey, error)
}

type DB struct {
    database.Manager
}

type RetailerKey struct {
    Id         int        `json:"id"`
    RetailerId int        `json:"retailer_id"`
    Key        string     `json:"key"`
    Enabled    *bool      `json:"enabled"`
    CreatedAt  *time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt  *time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}

func (db *DB) RetailerKeys() ([]*RetailerKey, error) {
    var keys []*RetailerKey
    if err := db.Find(&keys).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return keys, nil
}
```

project/lib/services/retailer_keys.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigateway"
    "gopkg.in/volatiletech/null.v6"

    "project/lib/models"
    "project/lib/services/api_keys"
)

func GetKeys() ([]*models.RetailerKey, error) {
    var q models.RetailerKeysInterface

    keys, err := q.RetailerKeys()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return keys, nil
}

func CreateKey(id int) (models.RetailerKey, error) {
    ...
}
```

Then be able to use it in my main package like:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    // "reflect"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"

    _ "project/lib/config"
    "project/lib/services"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    statusCode := 200

    keys, err := services.GetKeys()
    if err != nil {
        statusCode = 400
    }
    body, _ := json.Marshal(keys)

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Body:       string(body),
        StatusCode: statusCode,
    }, nil
}

...
```

I'd like to be able to embed the relevant subset of the Manager type in my models.

EDIT:
Edited the question/code based on feedback in comments.

This gives me an error: `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

Comment: Based on the quoted code, the error is accurate; `DB` does not have a `Find` method. What's the question?

Comment: @Adrian How to I then access the *gorm.DB in the models package?

Comment: `type Manager interface {}` defines no methods, embedding it into `DB` is not gonna magically reveal gorm's methods. You need to either define the gorm methods you want to use on Manager, or don't use the interface and embed gorm.DB into your DB.

Comment: E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/N6ZTiayl6pC

Comment: @mkopriva I think I get you, let me refactor and rephrase my question.

Comment: @drack I suggest you take the [go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). This `var q models.RetailerKeysInterface` and the line after, `keys, err := q.RetailerKeys()` indicates that you haven't yet grasped what interfaces in Go are, and how they work. And I'm not trying to be condescending, Go's interfaces are an important part of the language, they are very useful, and they are ubiquitous. Understanding Go's interfaces is key when programming in Go, knowing your tools makes your own life easier.

Comment: And to explaing the error message: `q` is `nil`, you haven't initialized any value that implements `RetailerKeysInterface` and assigned it to `q`. Calling a method on a `nil` interface value is what causes your program to crash, if nothing else.

Comment: Try going through these: [one](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9), [two](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces), [three](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces), [four](http://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-interface-implementation). And here you can see what's wrong: https://play.golang.org/p/yjwMLHToNP9 Also note the line numbers in the stack trace, they tell you where exactly you're making a mistake.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, going through the go tour now.

Answer (score 0):

I was definitely misunderstanding interfaces in go. After going through A Tour of Go it started to become clearer how it all fits together.

This is that I ended up doing for anyone that is going through the same thing. I'll leave the original question up so you can see the differences.

project/lib/database/mysql.go:

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" // Needed for gorm
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

var Manager *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error

    dsn := MysqlConnectionString("parseTime=true")
    tablePrefix := "qcommerce"

    gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, defaultTableName string) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v_%v", tablePrefix, defaultTableName)
    }

    Manager, err = gorm.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := Manager.DB().Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

project/lib/models/retailer_keys.go

```
package models

import (
    "project/lib/database"
    "time"
)

type QRetailerKeys interface {
    Insert() error
    Find() error
}

type RetailerKey struct {
    ID                  int        `json:"id"`
    RetailerID          int        `json:"retailer_id"`
    Retailer            Retailer   `json:"retailer"`
    Key                 string     `json:"key"`
    Enabled             bool       `json:"enabled" gorm:"DEFAULT:true"`
    CreatedAt           *time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt           *time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}

// RetailerKeys returns a slice of all keys in table
func RetailerKeys() ([]*RetailerKey, error) {
    var keys []*RetailerKey
    if err := database.Manager.Find(&keys).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return keys, nil
}

func (r *RetailerKey) Find() error {
    ...
}

// Create a new key
func (r *RetailerKey) Create() error {
    return database.Manager.Create(&r).Error
}
```

project/lib/services/retailer_keys.go

```
package services

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    // "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigateway"

    "partners.drinks.com/lib/models"
    "partners.drinks.com/lib/services/api_keys"
)

func sessionBuilder() *session.Session {
    config := &aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),
    }
    session := session.Must(session.NewSession(config))
    return session
}

func GetKeys() ([]*models.RetailerKey, error) {
    keys, err := models.RetailerKeys()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return keys, nil
}

func CreateKey(id int) (models.RetailerKey, error) {
    apikeys := &api_keys.ApiKeyBuilder{}
    base64Key := apikeys.GenUUID().GenKey().Base64

    var key = models.RetailerKey{
        RetailerID: id,
        Key: base64Key,
        Enabled: func(b bool)
    }

    if err := key.Create(); err != nil {
        return models.RetailerKey{}, err
    }
    ...

    return key, nil
}
```

I use it like:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"

    _ "partners.drinks.com/lib/config"
    "partners.drinks.com/lib/services"
)


func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    statusCode := 200

    keys, err := services.GetKeys()
    if err != nil {
        statusCode = 400
    }
    body, _ := json.Marshal(keys)

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Body:       string(body),
        StatusCode: statusCode,
    }, nil
}

...
```

Thanks to @mkopriva for the linked resources in the comments.