# How to resolve Too many connections

Tags: mysql, go

when I run this I get `Too many connections error` unfortunately I couldn't find the solution, I will generate 50 million data

main.go content

```golang
package main

import (
    "dopinghafiza-videoplayer-mysql/mysql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    

    var player mysql.Player

    player.Muted = 1
    player.UserId = 55
    player.PlayBackRate = "2.55"
    player.Volume = "4.5888"
    player.Volume = "2.55"

    connection := mysql.GetConnection()

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        player.Muted = int8(i % 2)
        player.UserId = i
        mysql.InsertPlayer(player, connection)

    }

}
```

insert.go file content

```golang
package mysql

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Player struct {
    UserId       int
    Muted        int8
    PlayBackRate string
    Volume       string
}

func InsertPlayer(player Player, db *sql.DB) {

    res := db.QueryRow("insert into players (muted,user_id,volume,play_back_rate) values (?,?,?,?)", player.Muted, player.UserId, player.Volume, player.PlayBackRate)
    db.Close()
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not close connections; Go comes indeed with some connection pooling.

You should also use `Exec()` instead of `QueryRow`, because you are keeping connection open since MySQL still has to send data (although it looks odd).

```go
func InsertPlayer(player Player, db *sql.DB) {
    res, err := db.Exec("insert into players (muted,user_id,volume,play_back_rate) values (?,?,?,?)",
        player.Muted,
        player.UserId,
        player.Volume,
        player.PlayBackRate)
    if err != nil {
        // and handle errors!
    }
    fmt.Println(res.RowsAffected())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't open and close the connection each time; that's wrong and has a huge cost for your application.

A better method is to use a singleton pattern, open the connection once, use it several times, and close the connection when your application closes, not after each query.

You can find the sample code for the singleton pattern here.

[How to create singleton DB class in GoLang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257847/how-to-create-singleton-db-class-in-golang)

Comment: ı know  singleton but  ı can't make in golang

Comment: @dılosürücü You can find the sample code on the above link.

Answer (score -1):

1. Login to mysql using `mysql -u root -p`
2. Use this command to see the value of **max_connections** `show variables like %max_conne%;`
3. Increase the value of **max_connections** using `set global max_connections = 4096;`

This will solve your issue.

Comment: You can try increasing the number of connections, 4096 is just a number.